# Gsuite Business - access calendars of users

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I have a Gsuite Business account and several users, I would like (in Python) to access the calendars (readonly) of all users, to display events in an app.

As a Super Admin, is there a way to do this without having to ask each user to agree that the app will access their calendar?

Comment: Use a service account and grant it access to the users gsuite accounts.

Comment: you need to see it up in gsuite or it won't have access

Comment: yes thanks, I found it in the mean time

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @DaImTo comment, creating a service account is indeed the way to go, and then following https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority this does the job

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'GOOGLE_SECRET.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('address@example.com')

google_calendar = googleapiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=delegated_credentials)

events = google_calendar.events().list(
    calendarId='address@example.com',
    maxResults=10
).execute()
```